# HTTP expire date and IIS 7.0 enabled, but not working

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic, browser-cache, pagespeed

I enabled in IIS manager-> MySite -> HTTP Response Headers  -> Set Common Headers -> Expire Web Content -> After 7 days.

This is correctly reflected in `web.config`. By the way both Google Page Speed online and Google Page Speed as Firebug extension are saying "expiration not specified".

Answer (score 1):

This setting impacts static content only not content generated by engines like asp and asp.net.

In additional IIS7 does not send the `Expires` header when responding to a HTTP/1.1 request, instead it uses the `Cache-Control` header instead.

In ASP-Classic you should use the `Response.Expires` property and the `AddHeader` method to add the `Cache-Control` header.   In ASP.NET the `Response.Cache` property exposes an object that has number of properties through which you can control caching both at the server and client end.

Comment: Actually cache headers are incorrect (`Cache-control non cache`) also for static GIF images. [Here the headers](http://i39.tinypic.com/33olczp.png).